# Opening Android Settings programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-settings

How can I open settings programmatically?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I used the code from the [most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19517448/12787264):

```java
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

It **opens the device settings in the same window**, thus got the users of my android application ([finnmglas/Launcher](https://github.com/finnmglas/Launcher)) for android stuck in there.

The answer **for 2020 and beyond** (in Kotlin):

```
startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS))
```

It works in my app, should also be working in yours without any unwanted consequences.

Comment: Thanks friend, please update your code like this:
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));

Comment: Solution came out after 7 years.

Comment: Here import for 'Settings' is import android.provider.Settings

Comment: I really love the 2020 solution as it enables you to easily open a specific category of the settings like the accessibility settings by simply using `Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS`

Answer (score 230):

You can open with

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

You can return by pressing back button on device.

Comment: any way to get back when user pressed Clear Cache button ?

Comment: @SweetWisherヅ You just have to edit the source code.

Comment: Now you can use 
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
There are whole bunch of constants for every main settings category that you can choose from. Just write Settings. and Android Studio will show you all categories in autocomplete.

Comment: Can I search a particular setting within Settings App and open that particular setting programmatically from my App? e.g. can I search OTG from my app in Settings of the phone?

Comment: It seems to me using StartActivity is enough, I get always get the result CANCELD when coming back to the App (which is normal when coming back with back button). Thus the app is not notified of changed settings this way.

Comment: @kjurkovic can you please explain why there is need to startActivityForResult, You can simply open setting app using    ===>         startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));

Comment: As this code opens settings in the same window, it can mess up the functionality of your app. Use the code from [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62092663/12787264) to prevent that.

Comment: @TheBlackHorse because with startActivityForResult you can do some checks if you need to when you come back to app from settings in `onActivityResult` method. It works with startActivity as well. 
@finnmglas Android doesn't have windows. It has activities - since settings is a separate app, with it's own activities, makes what you say totally stupid

Answer (score 44):

This did it for me

```
Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(callGPSSettingIntent);
```

When they press back it goes back to my app.

Comment: What Settings screen does this offer?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky it opens Location based settings inside the " Setting "

Answer (score 22):

You can try to call:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```

for other screen in setting screen, you can go to

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html

Hope help you in this case.

Comment: You require to pass "REQUEST_CODE" as 2nd argument of `startActivityForResult`.

Comment: Besides, he asked for General Settings. Not for Wifi settings. So why did you answer that?

Answer (score 14):

In case anyone finds this question and you want to open up settings for your specific application:

```
val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
intent.data = Uri.parse("package:" + context.packageName)
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can make another class for doing this kind of activities.

```
public class Go {

   public void Setting(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To achieve this just use an **[Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)** using the constant **[ACTION_SETTINGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html)**, specifically defined to show the System Settings:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
```

**[startActivityForResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))** is optional, only if you want to return some data when the settings activity is closed.

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

**[here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html)** you can find a list of contants to show specific settings or details of an aplication.

Answer (score 4):

Following the new api described on: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

```
private val goToSettingsRequest = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
) { activityResult ->
    // TODO: DEAL WITH THE CALLBACK
}

private fun goToSettings() {
    goToSettingsRequest.launch(Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this intent to open security and location screen in settings app of android device

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS));
```

Answer (score 1):

Send User to Settings With located Package, example for WRITE_SETTINGS permission:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS).setData(Uri.parse("package:"+getPackageName()) ),0);
```

Answer (score 1):

> open android location setting programmatically using alert dialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
alertDialog.setTitle("Enable Location");
alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
      }
});
alertDialog.show();
```