# Is it possible set expiry date of apk(application) android?

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to create an apk & set an expiry date in it , application will be automatically deleted from mobile device when that date comes. Don't want device to be rooted for this.Want the solution should work both for rooted & Unrooted device.Is it possible to do so?

Comment: You can simply check the current date. If it's past the expiration date, finish the app (after showing a message).

Comment: I want the app to be uninstalled from device not only finish it.Is it possible that app gets automatically uninstalled on specific date?

Comment: It's not possible. You have to ask user permissions AND the device HAS TO be rooted.

Comment: Thanks Vyger for the reply.Is it possible i send some notification at that specific date , when the user click on that option i take the user to page in settings that give the user option to uninstall the app Or when user click on that notification i display a pop up that gives the option of uninstalling the app?

Comment: Yes, it is. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517417/opening-android-settings-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks Vyger , appreciate you help.

Comment: For the notification part that's another question - you have to set an alarm on a specific date (with WakeLock, to survive reboots) and set a Notification and/or open the system settings page through a click on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible without a custom system, because you would need to do the following things:

- Edit Android's **Application Installer** to look in the application's manifest for something like **expirationDate** and compare it with current date.
- If the expiration date is not reached yet, you would start a new `Handler` thread to check the date every hour or every day, what you want.
- If the **expiration date** is reached then, the application would be automatically uninstalled.

And to install a custom system, you **MUST** root your device.