# Android Intent and Intent filter

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have a problem here with my code.
I want to pass from an activity to another from a button.
Here is my code:

MainActivity.class

```
ImageView imgsettings;
```

inside `onCreate()`

```
imgsettings = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgviewsettings);
imgsettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.SETTINGS"));                                
    }
});
```

AndroidManifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".AppSettings"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_app_settings" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SETTINGS" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter> 
</activity>
```

I really cannot find the problem. Everything seem right to me.

Comment: what is your question?The question it self not clear what you want.

Comment: Whenever I run the app it gives me an error:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.oldie.AppSettings}:java.lang.NullPointexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no action with the name `android.intent.action.SETTINGS`. Try to remove the `<intent-filter>` from your manifest and add this code snippet in the `onClick()` method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Take a look at this SO question [Opening Android Settings programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517417/opening-android-settings-programmatically)

Comment: I don't want to open the android OS Settings, I want to open an Activity that has the settings for my app.

Comment: Then just open a new activity `Intent intent = new Intent(this, AppSettings.class);
startActivity(intent); `  but remove all the `<intent-filter>` things from the manifest. Take a look at the official documentation about the self defined actions http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/action-element.html

Comment: I did it. I wrote exactly the same but still LogCat gives me an error.
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.oldie.AppSettings}:java.lang.NullPointexception

I cleaned my project in Eclipse and did it again. the same problem

Comment: Can you please debug and check if `imgsettings` is not null?

Comment: No. Sorry, it is null.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to deal with  for this.
You have to do startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,AppSettings.class)); to go to AppSettings activity.

Comment: I did it. I wrote:
public void onClick(View v) {
    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AppSettings.class);
    startActivity(intent);      
   }
It still gives me an error:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.oldie.AppSettings}:java.lang.NullPointexception

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your onClick method.

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, android.intent.action.SETTINGS.class);

MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: Did u try exactly this ?

Comment: Yes. But I found my problem. The problem is in the R.id.
The imgsettings variable returns null.