# Programmatically open a specific Android settings page without allowing the user to further navigate away from the application

Tags: android, android-settings

I am developing an application which will run in kiosk mode. In an Android application it is possible to [programmatically open a settings page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517417/opening-android-settings-programmatically), but how can I do so while preventing the user from further navigating into other settings via the button in the top left corner? Ideally I would like clicking the button in the top left of the opened settings page to return to my application which opened it instead of going to the main Android settings page where the user can change things that I don't want them to have access to from my kiosk mode application.

**EDIT**

Specifically, I am trying to open the Language Settings to change the language and culture on the device so that I can detect and change the language and culture in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Intent mechanism is not totally fine-grained. As you can see from the question you linked, you can open Settings application easily. With the exception of the [Location Settings page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19517455/471213), Android Settings application is not designed to provide fine grained control so that you cannot step back to the main settings screen.

I have taken a look at [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml), where you can find actions related to each settings page. In general, it could not be possible to isolate the user on a specific screen. For example, tablets show the entire settings navigation bar on the left.

Maybe you would like to tell us what settings page you want, and what settings you may want to edit. You might also think about using Android APIs to programmatically change *some* settings from your application, according to permissions.

Comment: I suspected that it's possible to change specific settings programmatically without entering the settings page. I'm going to explore using Android APIs to change the settings from my application as you suggest, I was just hoping what I asked might be possible so I could save myself the work. Thank you.