# How to open device admin settings from preferences?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent

This way perfectly opened summmary settings from my preferences.

```
<Preference android:title="@string/open_settings" >
    <intent android:action="android.settings.SETTINGS"/>
</Preference>
```

How to open Device Admin settings fragment?

Comment: maybe this will  [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49739998/how-to-open-up-phones-settings-page-through-preferences)

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the Intent manually

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19517448/11057458)