# Opening An App Submenu

Tags: java, android, submenu

```
public void opensettings(View view){
    Intent opensettingsapp = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.settings");
    startActivity(opensettingsapp);
}
```

What i've done wrong here?I try to open a submenu of an app but the app stop working.

Comment: Which submenu do you want to open?

Comment: what is meant by submenu ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening Android Settings programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517417/opening-android-settings-programmatically)

Comment: I find what i need public void action(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS));
    } .But how can I open this if i didn't activate this manually from menu(by pressing 5 times on build version) ? There is an app on Google Play that opens it without activate it manually...so there must be a solution